# How do I access the view block name?

Tags: theming, 8

How do I access the view block name?

```
function <theme_name>_theme_suggestions_views_view_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

 // print_r(array_keys($variables));
  if (isset($variables['view'])) {
    $view_id = $variables['view']->id();
    $view_block = 'testing';
    array_splice($suggestions, 1, 0, 'view__bundle__' . $view_id . '__' . $view_block);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure this is correct, but I guess you are looking for the `id` for the block:

```
function THEMENAME_theme_suggestions_views_view_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if (isset($variables['view'])) {
    $view_id = $variables['view'];
    $id = $view->id();
    $block_id = $view->getDisplay()->display['id'];
    array_splice($suggestions, 1, 0, 'view__bundle__' . $view_id . '__' . $block_id);
  }
}
```

You can also print out the contents of the `$view->getDisplay()->display` array to check for other values that you might use.

Comment: Thanks for the $view->getDisplay()->display tip that really helped